# error "windows could not display the images available for installation"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I am trying to install a new copy of windows 7 pro 64bit on the second partition of the HDD on my laptop but the windows setup throws an error "windows could not display the images available for installation".

In fact I've installed windows on the first partition years ago from the DVD media and also copy all contents of the DVD to the HDD. now the windows has gotten clunky and I want a fresh installation. I decided to install it from HDD but I received the mentioned error. The DVD drive has gotten broken and I do not have any USB DVD drive.

the installation media contains both Windows 7 32bit and 64bit and I could choose which version to be installed through a dialog during setup

How may I resolve the issue?

Comment: More than likely the W7 iso image you used to make the installer is bad

Comment: @Moab, actually I can install windows from that DVD on my other PC using DVD drive and the installation is done perfect but sounds like the copy not working

Comment: That's all I could find using google, you can answer your own question if you find the answer.